# Why Varchar datatype is not working in spark Dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

Actually I have a schema like,

```
val schema_tmp=Seq(StructField("Name",VarcharType(255),true),StructField("Id",VarcharType(255),true),StructField("Contact",VarcharType(255),true),StructField("I
    s_Active",CharType(10),true))
```

my source file like,
[Please click this link to see my source file snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIjjp.png)

while creating the dataframe,
Output:-

```
scala> val c=spark.read.format("csv").schema(StructType(schema_tmp)).option("header","false").load("sample2.txt")
scala.MatchError: VarcharType(255) (of class org.apache.spark.sql.types.VarcharType)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder$.externalDataTypeFor(RowEncoder.scala:215)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder$.externalDataTypeForInput(RowEncoder.scala:212)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.objects.ValidateExternalType.<init>(objects.scala:1699)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder$.$anonfun$serializerFor$3(RowEncoder.scala:175)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:245)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
```

Any one know this error please let me know?
If varchar type is supported or not?

Comment: What is the version of your spark? in Spark 2.4 VarcharType(length) is not supported (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/sql-reference.html), but in spark 3.2 it is (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datatypes.html)

Comment: Spark version 3.0.1 only..is their any other way to give size of the string?

Comment: Based on this document (https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/sql-ref-datatypes.html) it doesn't seem to be possible to limit the number of characters in a dataframe column using the schema.
You can implement the logic programmatically to fail when records in a column have more characters than a certain amount too.